# Wordpress category - list posts and subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

i've got problem with listing posts and subcategories in category page. What i need is:

**Main category page headline**

Subcategory 1

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

Subcategory 2

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

I working with custom post types, so it might be little bit harder. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code with post_type = your desired type

```
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catID);
foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
    echo '<h2>' . $subcat->cat_name . '</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    $args = array('post_type'    => 'post','category'=>$subcat->cat_ID);
    $subcat_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($subcat_posts as $subcat_post) {
        $postID = $subcat_post->ID;
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($postID) . '">';
        echo get_the_title($postID);
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works fine, but that's just a half i need. This list is ok, but it must be specific.

When I click on Main Category 1, which has subcategory1 and post1

I wanna see:

**Main category page headline**

Subcategory 1

- post 1

Same as for example when I click on Main Category 2, which has subcategory2 (with post2), subcategory3 (with post3)

I wanna see:

**Main category 2 page headline**

Subcategory 2

- post 2

Subcategory 3

- post 3

Answer (score -1):

Finally i figure out like this:

```
<?php 

$parentCatName = single_cat_title('',false);
$catID = get_cat_ID($parentCatName);
$parentCatID = get_cat_ID($parentCatName);
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of='.$parentCatID ); 
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catID);

  ?> 
 <?php  foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <div class="genre_subcat">
        <?php query_posts("cat=$cat->cat_ID&showposts=-1&order=ASC&orderby=name&post_type=armatury-voda"); ?>
        <h2><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
        <small><?php echo category_description($cat->cat_ID); ?></small>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post hentry"> 
      <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail'); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url[0]; ?>" alt="" width="150" /> 
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
$myname = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'kestazeni', true);
if ( $myname ) {  ?>

        <div class="dont"><a href="<?php echo do_shortcode ('[field "kestazeni"]'); ?>">Stáhnout PDF</a></div>

 <?php
}
else {
echo '';
}
?>

            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>    
      <?php }?>
```